Someone wants to pay me to be his texting buddy. How am I being scammed?
This man says he needs a texting buddy: someone he could give attention, talk and share things with and he will pay 600 dollars.
He says he is 41 from Omaha, Nebraska, and he is really doing this because college students need financial support from people who have it for rent and paying bills.
I said OK. Then he says he wants to go ahead and get my first allowance and wanted to know what institution I bank with. He is going to send me a check and then I'm supposed to deposit it

You have done well to ask. It's this https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/133556/sugar-daddy-wants-money-returned-to-bitcoin-for-his-son but so far only the first part.

Its best if you just cut this communication off. Depending upon the skill of this person they may convince you to give them some of your hard earned money. You don't need this aggravation in your life, just block the number.

Honestly: They might not want your money, but your nudes. You can decide what's worse.

If your alarm bells are ringing, the answer to "how am I being scammed" is "it doesn't matter". Scammers can have a litany of reasonable-sounding explanations for things that just don't smell right. Avoiding a scam doesn't require understanding it, and not understanding it doesn't mean it's not a scam.

@NuclearHoagie It's extremely important to ask and learn "how am I being scammed" because the next scammer may be more clever and employ tactics that won't immediately ring any alarm bells. Learning a general principle may help raise alarm bells in less obvious cases.

"Sugar daddies" are a legitimate thing... depending on how you define "legitimate" (some people, especially straight men, are lonely and willing to pay for company, others might just like treating people). But there is certainly plenty reason to be cautious, and most scams start from them telling you you can make some "easy money". And scammers are in the business of manipulating and tricking people, so even if you try to proceed very cautiously, there's still a good chance of getting swept up into a terrible situation before you figure out what's going on.

@AakashM don't link to downvoted dupes. Instead, link the better question. https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/109924/am-i-being-scammed-by-a-sugar-daddy

This question is similar to: Am I being scammed by a sugar daddy?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Why does he need to know your bank if he's "sending a check"?

I'm told (and it MAY be wrong) that Western Union payments are 100% one way and non reversible once they have been paid into a recipients bank account. Consider suggesting WU and see how they respond.

THIS IS OF COURSE A SCAM  It's totally incredible on this site that "Is this a scam" questions are answered and commented in such a half-assed faffing manner.

@RussellMcMahon: I believe some of the other answers tagged "scam" have examples of how Western Union -- or at least the appearance of Western Union -- can be abused.

It could also be money laundering of some sort, i.e. even if he just convinces you to send the same money back, it "cleans" the money

Always ask yourself why you and not any of the billions of other people in the world. If you don't have a good answer for that, it's probably a scam of some flavor.

No scammer will send you $600 going from their pocket into yours. So you can bet the money comes from a hacked bank account, or a scamming victim etc. Most likely your bank will eventually figure this out and remove th $600 from your account.
One possible scam is overpaying you “by mistake”, say putting $6,000 into your account instead of $600 and asking you to return the difference. So you pay $5,400 to the scammer, and three weeks from now your bank takes the $6,000 back and your account is at minus $5,400.
Or it’s just used for identity theft, or money laundering, but I think trying to take your money is the most common situation.

Absolutely. If you do get a check don't cash it, just say you've changed your mind and send it back. When they don't immediately give you a physical mailing address then tear it in two and send them a pic of the torn check.

Good for you for asking the question!
DO NOT provide this person ANY more personal information than you have already provided.  DO NOT give them a physical address, if you haven't already.  ESPECIALLY DO NOT give them any information about your financial accounts.  Not even the name.  Nothing.
The potential for scamming and stalking is legitimate.  Every bit of additional information you provide increases your risk.  ESPECIALLY DO not assume that just because you don't see the scam that there is no potential for it.
Based on what you've provided, it is EXTREMELY likely he is scamming you.
You ask, "how is he trying to scam me".  Impossible to say exactly how this particular person could be trying to scam you, we don't have all the facts, but scammers will gather little bits of personal information and use it together to exploit their victims.  It takes very little for a persistent scammer to exploit.  As an example, a scammer can give you a check, you deposit it, the scammer asks for a little of the money back for some reason, and then the check turns out to be no good.  OR, a scammer gets enough of your bank information, seizes control of your account and cleans it out, and then disappears.  There are many many other scenarios and it depends on exactly and specifically all of the information you have provided to the scammer.
Stalkers get cell phones and addresses and once the relationship does not go how they wish, the harassing begins.  Up to and including physical danger.
Seriously, disengage.  Don't explain, just disengage.  Even better, change your number.

The best part of this answer is DISENGAGE. Upvoted

@Vicky I disagree with the definitive assertion that it's a scammer based on the provided depiction. The world couldn't exist if everything operated on a zero-trust basis. When do you ever have a conversation with a person, and they don't immediately ask you a question related to your personal identity, outside a strictly professional context? This is likely a scam, but there is definitely a "safe relationship", if you engage without exposing any information that isn't already publicly tied to you. Changing your number is a mind-boggling overreaction unless you feel seriously threatened.

@natiiix I agree changing the number is an overreaction. But this is 100% definitively a scammer. Or possibly, I suppose, 0.00001% likely, not a scammer but just a weirdo, either way, not someone you want to have a relationship of any sort with. Find me a real person who is looking for a conversation with an online stranger and willing to pay $600 because he thinks "college students need help" and is not either a scammer or a weirdo.

@Vicky I absolutely agree that, disregarding the scammer aspect, that person does not sound like someone most people would want to interact with. That being said, the Internet has an ample supply of bizarre interactions, i.e. "weirdos", and someone legitimately giving out money to strangers isn't entirely unheard of. Of course, the opposite is vastly more common. Either way, OP is right to be a) suspicious, and b) curious about how this could lead to a scam. Scepticism and education/awareness are extremely important these days. :)

I think the OP could legitimately ask, "how can I interact with this person safely?"  I think there are answers to that.

"You ask, "how is he trying to scam me". Impossible to say" Please don't ADD MORE CONFUSION to "Am I being scammed" questions.  if you're not knowledgeable about scams - why answer?  This is an extremely well known and well understood popular scam, explained fully by Gnasher answer below.

@Fattie I've added some further details to address your concern.  HOWEVER, we simply do not have all the facts, so we cannot possibly know exactly what is happening.  Gnasher notes "one possible scam".  There are many other things that could be going on here.

Looking for definitive answers is an impossible bar on this site.  For example in almost all cases it's generally a good idea to pay off your high interest debt first, but for all we know we're going to be in a nuclear war in a year wiping out the financial and social infrastructure of the country and you were much better off buying guns and gold.  The overwhelming odds are that this is some sort of scam, and I don't understand the pushback to answering it as such.

@Chuu  I've added a para to address your concern, "Based on what you've provided, it is EXTREMELY likely he is scamming you."

This is what is called a "sugar daddy" scam. If there's no sex involved, then most likely the goal is to steal your identity one way or another, or use you for money laundering by sending money to you from one (forged/fraudulent/stolen/otherwise illegally obtained source) and receiving money from you to another (clean/legitimate) destination, leaving you holding the bag as the end-point of the string of fraudulent transactions.
As others have said, the more information you share the easier it is to steal your identity, and once money starts changing hands - that's when the money laundering phase starts.

A PG13 variant on the sugar daddy.

There are a lot of good answers here, but I wanted to give my thoughts as well. First and foremost, as others have suggested, you should immediately dissengage with this person. Whatever the plan, no normal person pays a random stranger $600 to be a txting buddy.
As for your question about how exactly you're being scammed. A couple of thoughts.
Some scammers may engage in a "long con", taking weeks or months or even longer to gain the trust of their intended victim.
All scams ultimately are financial in nature, but the way they get to that varies.
You mentioned that this is an "allowance" but haven't mentioned how frequent these $600 payments will be made.
Even if these payments are monthly, the scammer will be expecting quite a lot of "sharing" for that amount of money.
A common scam involves the scammer convincing a female (usually) victim to send personal, and then intimate photos. The ruse of trust may last just long enough for the scammer to get enough leverage that they can start demanding ever more explicit photos and videos, with threats that the photos they already have will be forwarded to the victims family, or co-workers, or school.

I'd like to add something to the "no normal person pays $600 for this" that I see very often forgotten on this SE: That people who have so much money that $600 (or whatever) is pocket change to them don't need to contact strangers. They can hire a professional, have a personal assistant to bother or can just go somewhere and buy a VIP ticket (which gets you plenty of attention).

@Tom That's true. It's not that it's an especially large amount. However, it's just plain weird. Very strange that the OP would have initially agreed to it. Such a creepy request.

" A couple of thoughts" no need to guess at this well known false-source scam.  Fully explained in the answer by gnasher.

Yes, this looks like a scam. Here's how the scam might work:
Fake Check: The scammer sends you a fake check. You deposit it, and the bank credits the money to your account. But after a few days, the bank finds out the check is fake and takes the money back. If you've already spent or sent the money, you'll have to pay it back to the bank.
Personal Information: The scammer might be trying to get your personal information, like your bank details, to steal from you or access your account.
Money Laundering: Sometimes, scammers use people to move stolen money. They might ask you to send part of the money to someone else, which could get you in trouble with the law.
You can start playing along with him, ask for a photo or personal information, but be careful, don’t fall for any tricks! I love messing with scammers and wasting their time!

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

chatgpt answer?
